# How to get access to sprite 2D context?

Tags: haxe, openfl

Is it possible to get the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` at a sprite level instead of the whole canvas?
Has anyone tried to have access for it? any idea?

I tried:

```
child.addEventListener(RenderEvent.RENDER_CANVAS, function(event)
        {
            var renderer:openfl.display.DisplayObjectRenderer = event.renderer;         
            var ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D = renderer.context;
            ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
            ctx.shadowColor = "black";
        });
```

However, I am getting error:

```
openfl.display.DisplayObjectRenderer has no field context
```

How would I access the sprite’s CanvasRenderingContext2D ?

Comment: What type is `child`? Is it possible to promote `event.renderer` to a `CanvasRenderer` or one of the other types that extend `DisplayObjectRenderer`? It looks like only the types that extend `DisplayObjectRenderer` have access to a rendering context.

Comment: `child` is Sprite type

Comment: Can you just cast `renderer` to a `CanvasRenderer`? I'm sure it was probably downcast from a `CanvasRenderer` to fit the definition of `RenderEvent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this casting the `renderer` to a `CanvasRenderer`:

```
child.addEventListener(RenderEvent.RENDER_CANVAS, function(event)
        {
            var renderer:openfl.display.CanvasRenderer = cast(event.renderer);         
            var ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D = renderer.context;
            ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
            ctx.shadowColor = "black";
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! that has worked, but I've noticed that `shadowBlur ` was applied on all sprites, although I only added the event listener to a particular child

Comment: Well, the context is shared by all sprites being rendered in the canvas. I'm not totally sure if OpenFL exposes something to augment sprite instances (although, I'm sure it has to be possible. Seems a pretty common task, I'd check the documentation)

Comment: Thanks, it would be awesome to apply effects at Sprite level